# $\forall m\in\mathbb N\exists n>m+1\exists N\in\mathbb N:m^2+n^2+(mn)^2=N^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, conjectures

Prove the conjecture or give a counter-example:

For each $m\in\mathbb N$ there exist a $n>m+1$ such that $m^2+n^2+(mn)^2$ is a perfect square.

I have just tried it out numerically and it holds for $m<1000$.

I can't see any pattern for the smallest $n$:

```
m  n

1 12
2 8
3 18
4 32
5 50
6 72
7 98
8 30
9 162
10 200
11 242
12 119
13 338
14 392
15 450
16 512
17 578
18 105
19 722
20 800
21 208
22 968
23 1058
24 1152
25 1250
```

Comment: Did you look whether you find some pattern among the few smallest such $n$ for each $m$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'll try!

Comment: There is a rather clear pattern...

Comment: @Wojowu: Tell me!

Comment: $2m^2$. Okay, I admit this pattern doesn't hold for all $m$, but just looking at $m=2,3,4,5,6,7$ should give some idea.

Comment: @Wojowu: I didn't saw that. But it isn't general, there are exceptions as 1, 8, ...

Comment: Indeed. But maybe this will suggest that taking $n=2m^2$ works...?

Comment: I didn't mean to take the smallest such $n$ for each $m$, but that for each $m$ you look at the few smallest $n$. You would probably have spotted the multiples of $m$ among those, and then maybe a pattern for the smallest such $n$ that are multiples of $m$. This could have lead to the fundamental solutions of the Pell equations $x^2 - (m^2+1)y^2 = 1$. (with $x = N/m$ and $y = n/m$)

Comment: @DanielFischer: I see. It seems to work alright. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conjecture is true.

Fix $m\ge 1$. You need that $n^2(m^2+1)+m^2$ is a square. It would be enough to find such a $n$ with the additional condition that it is divisible by $m$, let us say $n=mA$. After dividing by $m^2$, it would be enough to find positive integers $A,B$ (with $A$ sufficiently large) such that
$$
(m^2+1)A^2-B^2=1.
$$
Start with the basic solution $(1,m)$, and then construct infinitely many ones with Pell's equation method (see, e.g., equation (37) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html)).

Answer (score 3):

I might as well turn my comments into an answer...

For $m>1$ it is easy to see $n=2m^2$ works. Indeed, $n>m^2>m+1$ and
$$m^2+n^2+(mn)^2=m^2+4m^4+4m^3=m^2(1+4m+4m^2)=m^2(1+2m)^2=(m+2m^2)^2.$$